# Throughput For Each Worker Goes Down When Decreasing Parallelism

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I have a simple stateless Flink application running on Kubernetes that reads from a Kafka topic and prints out content. The input TPS is consistently high (> 3K) and the number of partitions on that topic is 180. When running with higher parallelism (for example 3), I notice that each worker can process up to 1K records/sec. However, when I have a lower degree of parallelism (2 and 1), the throughput for each worker significantly goes down, sometimes even to 0 records/sec. What could be the reason for such behavior? And would it be possible to mitigate? I am running on Flink 1.12, with unaligned checkpointing enabled. I also checked if there was back pressure on any of the operators, but all show OK.

Thank you!

Comment: Can you share some details on what the job does? I guess it is more than just reading and printing. Do you know if the input is equally distributed over all partitions? Did you checked the memory metrics? If the job just stops it might be the garbage collector being to busy.

Comment: To reproduce the issue with minimal steps, that's all the pipeline does (read from Kafka and print content). I even disabled checkpointing to see if that was causing the bottleneck, but the issue still persists. Memory usage is fine and the GC activity does not take more than 1% of the CPU usage. However, what I did notice was that CPU usage was always high (> 95%)

Comment: Interesting ... does the consumer creates 180 threads? Just a thought